# React Native Save Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I am trying to get my EditProfile page to simply go to another page after pressing "Done".

Thus far I have got it to "Save" the updates/changes,etc. But after saving, i want it to navigate to the 'Home' page.

Can i put something into headerRight? Or put it into updateUser?

Heres what i have so far:

```
headerRight: (
  <TouchableHighlight
    //onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
    onPress= {navigation.state.params.updateUser}>
    <Text style={{color:'red', marginRight: 5, fontSize:17, fontWeight: '600'}}>Done</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  )



updateUser = () => {
  const about = this.state.about
  const {uid} = this.props.navigation.state.params
  //const {navigate} = this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
  firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid)
    .update({about})
}



  <TextInput
    style={{height: 150, color: 'grey', fontSize:14, padding: 20, paddingTop: 10, borderColor: '#d3d3d3', backgroundColor:'#fcfcfc', borderWidth: 1}}
    multiline = {true}
    numberOfLines = {5}
    onChangeText={val => this.setState({about:val})}
    value={this.state.about}
  />
```

Comment: Actually what i need it to do is = When user clicks "Done" =  just go back to the PREVIOUS page it was on.

ie: Just CLOSE the screen its currently on.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase update() returns a promise and you can simply append .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate(“Home”))

Comment: Where would I put that? Pls show where/how it can be used. Thank you

Comment: In updateUser function, firebase.database().ref(“users”).child(uid).update({about}).then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate(“Home”))